# Limit CSS selector scope

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This is a bit weird and maybe is wrong but that's what I want to do...

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="item is-active">
    <div class="item-part"></div>

    <div class="item small">
        <div class="item-part">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And with CSS I want to do this:

```
.item.is-active  .item-part {
    outline:1px solid red;
}
```

The problem is that the inner `.item-part` will also be outlined which is not desirable. I want an `.item-part` to be outlined only if its closest `.item` is `.is-active`.

I'd rather not use JS for this nor a `direct-sibling` selector since the html may differ.
I also don't want to override the rule like this:

```
.item:not(.is-active) .item-part {
        outline:none;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/sjsYx/) with a live example

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about (Assuming only one element has the `is-active` class):

```
.item.is-active .item-part {
    outline:1px solid red; /* active item part style */
}
.item.is-active .item .item-part {/* e.g. child of iten that is not active*/
    outline: none; /* disable active item part style */
}
```

If you can't modify the class names, won't use javascript, and the direct descendant solution doesn't work (e.g. because there may be wrapper-div's sometimes); this is the only solution I can think of...

Comment: I'd prefer not to override the selector, since I may have more that one modifiers like `.is-active`

Answer (score 0):

Just override the style for when your element doesn't have an `is-active` class:

```css
.item.is-active  .item-part {
    outline:1px solid red;
}

.item.is-active .item .item-part,
.item .item-part {
    outline:none;
}
```

The `.item.is-active  .item-part` has higher specificty than the `.item .item-part` selector, so this will always be applied to the `.item-part` descendants.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/sjsYx/6/).

Comment: The cool thing is that this would work for n nested `.item` but as I said, I don't want and override rule since I may have more than one modifiers like `.is-active`

Comment: @xpy it doesn't make any sense as you are just complicating the scenario to be true

Comment: @Mr.Alien I know it's a bit complicated, I don't even know if it is possible with my restrictions, that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: @xpy if you have more modifiers then you'll have to cater for those in your CSS.

Comment: @xpy Hmm, specificity problem; that can be fixed by adding `.item.is-active .item.is-active .item-part` alongside the `.item.is-active .item-part` selector: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/sjsYx/9/).

Comment: @JamesDonnelly then it won't work for n nested `.item`